# Need list of HDD devices excluding my os HDD

Tags: hard-disk, hardware, devices

I want list out whole HDD device excluding my os running device attached to my system. I did lot's of googling and fired many more commands in command line of linux. but can't gating proper output.

One command which give all device including my os device.

```
fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | grep "Disk \/" | grep -v "\/dev\/md" | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/://g'
```

output:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
```

By "OS HDD" I mean the hard disk that holds the partition that holds the `/` file system.

Comment: This is definitely possible becomes somewhat difficult when you take into account LVM/DeviceMapper and MD devices. For example, your `grep -v` omits the MD device, but doesn't do any checking to see if a block device is part of a root mirror, if a particular block device is mounted as part of root, etc. Basically, an accurate solution would be pretty involved so this might be a case where it's better that you tell us what your end goal is and we can tell you if there's an easier way to accomplish it.

Comment: Joel Davis@Thanks. Suppose i attach two SATA HDDs on my system and i have one internal HDD which have OS. Now i have three HDDs. if i run above command(in question), it list out all HDDs with logical name. Here i can not predict which HDD(Logical name) contain OS which running currently. So first i need to find out HDD with logical name which contain currently running OS. here my question raise, But how? is there way to find out it?

Comment: There is a way but it's a lot of work which is why I'm asking why you're wanting to do that. I understand you're trying to track new HDD's and filter out the ones that contain "the OS" but "OS" is pretty broad. I'd imagine you'd include `/` in that but what about `/usr/local/` or `/home` if they're on a different volume? Are they part of the OS too? Ultimately, you can enumerate all devices by a `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path` but the hard part is knowing which parts of the system you want to call "OS" and writing the logic to filter them out.

Comment: My "what are you trying to do" question was more about "What problem are you trying to fix by enumerating non-OS filesystems?" Since the other way is possible but doing it correctly may be more work than you need to do given whatever you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Joel Davis@Thanks  /-it root directory. Now my ultimate goal is listing all HDD logical name list excluding my OS HDD. through this logical name User can search Files from existing HDDs list through GUI. that's why i would not send existing OS HDD to user.

Answer (score 0):

`df /` shows what block device the root filesystem is on. You can parse it this way:

```
root_device=$(df -P / | awk 'NR!=1 {print $1}')
```

If you're using PC partitions without LVM or RAID, the root device will be `/dev/hdZ9` or `/dev/sdZ9` where `Z` is a lowercase letter that designates the disk and `9` is a number that designates the partition. You can extract the disk part this way:

```
root_disk=${root_device#[0-9]}; root_disk=${root_disk#[0-9]}
```

The complete list of disks and other block devices is available in `/sys/block`.

Beware that with RAID, LVM, etc., this can get very complicated. Whatever your program does, it's unlikely to work with hardware configurations that you hadn't thought of. So be sure to implement some thorough error checking.

Comment: The first partition on the disk is numbered `1`, not `0`. And/but especially with e.g. GPT you certainly can have more than nine partitions on a disk. Just goes to prove your point about this being a Hard Problem to solve generally, I guess!

Comment: @MichaelKjörling My code accommodates for 99 partitions. Yeah, so it would also work with `root_disk=${root_device#[1-9]}; root_disk=${root_disk#[0-9]}`, so what?